# Magento catalog product list soap API is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, soap-api-v2, soap-api-v1

I'm trying to access magento product catalog data using magento API.

I'm trying sample code provided by magento

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

// If somestuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.list');
var_dump($result);

// If you don't need the session anymore
//$client->endSession($session);
```

All the API(s) are working fine expect the catalog product list.

I'm getting following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Call to a member function getRole() on null in G:\wamp64\www\mage-api\index.php on line 11
( ! ) SoapFault: Call to a member function getRole() on null in G:\wamp64\www\mage-api\index.php on line 11
```

**I have created API user with full access role and it's working fine with all the API expect catalog list.**

Any solution ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think You have not created role in admin @Ashvini Maewal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and after a long debugging session, I found out that the error is caused by the extension `MagentoHackathon_AdvancedAcl`. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/AdvancedAcl/issues/27) and created a [pull request](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/AdvancedAcl/pull/28), which fixes this issue.

The problem is that they execute the following code:

```
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getRole();
```

But in the case of a SOAP API call, there is no user in the admin session.

Answer (score 0):

you have to follow the below Steps to Create the Api User & Api Key

```
https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magebridge/administration/596-step-by-step-create-a-magento-api-user
```

Then you have to use Api key & User name in your Code below

```
$session = $client->login('apiUser here you have to change user name ', 'apiKey here you have to change key ');
```

Comment: i  have created API user with full role and it's working for rest all magento soap api.

Comment: @AshviniMarwal Any help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/262653/57334